# Emacs code validation

Tags: validation, emacs

I am having a hard time finding code validation solutions for emacs, something/s to check that my javascript / css / ruby etc is valid code, where is all this stuff at?

Comment: Scala guys are lucky here: they've got "scala-mode + ensime" for Emacs, which does real-time validation of the source code under Emacs (even on incomplete ASTs) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to basic syntactic correctness, in which case you should look at [flymake](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake), which is included with Emacs, and which runs a validation program in the background, parses its output, and marks up the buffer with errors and warnings.

And, to get you started, here is a small module for using [flymake with Ruby](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/site-lisp/flymake-ruby/flymake-ruby.el), and a similar one for [flymake with javascript using jslint](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/site-lisp/flymake-js/flymake-js.el) as the validation program.

Answer (score 0):

that's why you test ruby mate. Even js has test suites now too.

As for the css, you can always use things like autopair, or textmate.el to ensure you close your hashes, and maybe even add the semi-colon to your css as well (I should see if that exists actually, thanks).

Answer (score 0):

for js - there is an emacs wiki page but it seems to be quite out of date: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript

Here's what I did instead. First I installed `jslint` on `node.js`

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
npm install jslint
ln -s ~/.npm/jslint/0.1.8/package/bin/jslint.js ~/.local/bin/
```

For emacs integration I then tried installing the package `flymake-jslint` in emacs (I'm using emacs24 with included package manager) and pointing it at `jslint` but it just wouldn't work.

I then followed the instructions here http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/59 - I created a bash wrapper script for `jslint.js` and pointed the .el snippet at it and it works fine.